# Why is there no "purge" command in apt's manpage

Tags: apt, manpage, purge

> CLI for apt.
>
> Basic commands:
>
> > list - list packages based on package names
> >
> > search - search in package descriptions
> >
> > show - show package details
>
> -
>
> > update - update list of available packages
>
> -
>
> > install - install packages
> >
> > remove  - remove packages
>
> -
>
> > upgrade - upgrade the system by installing/upgrading packages
> >
> > full-upgrade - upgrade the system by removing/installing/upgrading packages
>
> -
>
> > edit-sources - edit the source information file

As you can see, it misses a purge option, but I still can type "apt purge" to remove packages, why doesn't it in its manpage?

Comment: The text you have quoted is from `apt`'s help, not from the manpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the changelog of apt](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/debian/changelog#L1872), `apt purge` was added in `apt` package version `0.9.14.3~exp3` (dated 18 Jan, 2014):

```
apt (0.9.14.3~exp3) experimental; urgency=low

* add "apt purge"
```

This behaves the same way as `apt-get purge` but the `man` page lacks the mention.

From [`cmdline/apt.cc`](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/master/cmdline/apt.cc#L69) of `apt` source code:

```
// package stuff
{"install",&DoInstall},
{"remove", &DoInstall},
{"purge", &DoInstall},
```

This should definitely go in a bug report.

Also note that, the `apt` command is evolving and the plan is to incorporate all the options of `apt-get` to `apt` in the process.

---

The [`man apt` of Xenial (16.04)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html) has it (Thanks @muru).

Comment: 16.04's manpage mentions it: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt.8.html.

Comment: @muru Cool...was looking for that..

Answer (score 0):

From man apt:

```
"APT is a management system for software packages."
```

From man apt-get:

```
"apt-get is the command-line tool for handling packages."
```

So apt-get is a commandline interface for using apt.

Also in the man-page of `apt-get`, we read

[image]

Comment: apt (Advanced Package Tool) is the command-line tool for handling packages. It provides a commandline
       interface for the package management of the system. See also apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8) for more low-level
       command options.

Comment: It is written in its manpage.

Comment: They both are command-line tools.

Comment: This is wrong..`apt` itself is now a standalone command to manage the apt interface..

Comment: @heemayl Is `apt` more like an interface to `apt-get` then? It's not exactly crystal clear how apt (& apt-get) and dpkg work together (at least nothing I've found in man pages). I only noticed `apt` lately since it doesn't need sudo to run

Comment: @Xen2050 Yeah, its somewhat confusing at first..`apt` command is actually a high level tool for the apt package management system..it has no direct relation with `apt-get` (or brothers), they both manages(uses) the underlying apt library..